# Implicit type conversion with templated function parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, implicit-conversion

If I have a simple function expecting a type like:

```
class X
{
    public:
        X( int ){}
};

void fx( X  ) {}



fx( 1 ); // implicit converted to X(int); // fine!
```

If I try the same for templated types, it will not work.

```
template <typename T>
class Y
{
    public:
        Y( T ){};
};

template <typename T>
void fy( Y<T> );

fy( 2 ); // Y<int> expected, but it fails
```

Is there any trick to force the conversion?

It is needed to do it implicit, a direct access on fy is *not* what is wanted. I know that I can force all templates with specifying the template parameters ;)

Comment: @Ron: Sorry to be non precise enough: For me it was important to get it implicit. Manually defining the template parms did not help in my use case.

Comment: `Y<const int&>`, `Y<int>`, `Y<int&&>` would be viable. How do you expect compiler to decide ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implicit conversions won't be considered in [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions); the template parameter `T` just can't be deduced.

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for overload resolution, which happens later.

You can write a helper function template.

```
template <typename T>
void helper(T&& t) {
    fy<std::decay_t<T>>(std::forward<T>(t)); // specify the template argument explicitly
}
```

then

```
helper(2); // T will be deduced as int
```

Comment: OK, so the answer is simply: No! :-) because I though about writing a helper which needs implicit conversion, writing a helper which did it explicit is the opposite of my basic idea. My idea was simply based on "implicit" conversion so it simply was not a possible way. Thanks!

Comment: @songyuanyao: You probably want `std::decay_t<T>` to handle (const) references.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have implicit conversion and template deduction in the argument. Another way to break it up:

```
template <typename T>
void fy( T x ) {
    Y<T> y = x;
    //Use y
    return;
}
```

Of course, depending on `fy` you may be able to use `x` directly as `T`, and convert implicitly on the fly in the function.

Comment: If you already have the code for `fy(Y<T>)` you could just write `template <class T>
void fy(T x) { fy(Y<T>(x)); }` as overload wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Template argument deduction does not take any implicit conversions into account.

You can manually specify the desired instantiation:

```
fy<int>(2);
```

Using template type deduction with C++17, you can also go with

```
fy(Y(2));
```

and with pre-C++17

```
fy(Y<int>(2));
```

Comment: Sorry to be non precise enough: For me it was important to get it implicit. Manually defining the template parms did not help in my use case.