Why does implicit conversion fail when converting a std::basic_string to std::basic_string_view?
Based on this three points:
1. using string  = basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char>>
2. using string_view = basic_string_view<char, char_traits<char>>
3. operator std::basic_string_view<CharT, Traits>() const noexcept //defined for std::basic_string

(for reference 1, 2, and 3). Pay attention to point 3, which provides the conversion of a string to a string_view.
Thus, the following code compiles correctly:
void foo(std::string_view v){
    std::cout<<"ok";
}

int main(){
    foo(std::string{"abc"});
}

But implicit conversion does not work if we want to abstract from the character type, i.e.
template<class CharT, class Traits>
void foo(std::basic_string_view<CharT, Traits> v){
    std::cout<<"ok";
}
int main(){
    foo(std::basic_string<char>{"abc"});
}

Godbolt
Q: Where exactly does the C++20 language standard prohibit/not allow the implicit conversion presented above?

Conversions are not considered in template parameter deduction. I'm sure there is a dupe for it.

I think this is the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51609496/implicit-type-conversion-with-templated-function-parameters

Because templates do never do implicit type conversion. Whenever you have template functions you need an exact match,. "abd" has a type const char* and this doesn't match the std::basic_string_view<CharT,Traits> type. In fact I often use this fact to avoid functions being called with implicit conversions. e.g. using pre C++20 syntax template<typename T> auto f(T) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<int,T>,void>. After C++20 you can use requires syntax.

@PepijnKramer Thank for the advice you provided. I often use a similar construction for the bool and char types. This question was closed because I received an answer in the comments

As possible motivation, it would require the compiler to go through all possible instantiations of std::basic_string_view in order to see if there is a suitable implicit conversion to one of those types. This would take approximately forever.

generally there are unbounded many implicit conversions to be taken into account. And even if the compiler would consider them all, only in rare cases the conversion would be unambiguous.

"Based on 1, 2, 3, we know the following:" -- Questions are supposed to be self-contained, not relying on external links for key information. How do the numbers "1, 2, 3" tell us something about strings?

@JaMiT These numbers are used to provide links to an authoritative source of information, which leads us to a list of quotations from three points. I think supplementing the question with quotes from authoritative sources is a something basic for a good question.

@JaMiT this is just a matter of wording, the links are nice references, the essential information is in the question. Though, I agree it could be worded better

@PavelDev " I think supplementing the question with quotes from authoritative sources is a something basic for a good question" -- I agree, but there was no way to determine that this was your intent from the way you wrote your question. You just threw out links with no explanation. You didn't even think it important to mention which site you were linking to.
